# unusual code processing vb.net

Tags: vb.net

I am trying here to get the rows from the CSV file I tried it before and was no problem until now in the new project:

I am adding each row in list of structure which has (array of folders() and 3 other variables)

The problem is when i am using list.add() is working fine at the first time but for the second row when accessing the folder data from the arraycurrentrow() it is updating the previous item in the list even the code didn’t reach the list.add() part !!!!

Note: this happen only in array part but for the 3 other variables in the structure no problem

Note: i used the same code for another project but the structure hadnt any arrays ? so why the problem in the array of Folders()

I am spending all day with no hope !! If you have any idea for this problem

```
    Public Structure DataBaseStrc
        Public Property Folders As String()
        Public Property TagName As String
        Public Property SAPFL As String
        Public Property SAPEqNO As String
    End Structure






Shared Function MarafiqsDataBase_CSV()
        Dim ioReader As New Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO.TextFieldParser(DataBaseInserter.DatabaseCSVPathText.Text)
        ioReader.TextFieldType = FileIO.FieldType.Delimited
        ioReader.SetDelimiters(",")

        Dim tempList As New List(Of DataBaseStrc)
        Dim ReadingIndex As Integer
        Dim StrcCurrentRow As DataBaseStrc = Nothing
        Integer.TryParse(DataBaseInserter.MaxFoldersNoCB.Text, MaxFolderNo)
        ReDim StrcCurrentRow.Folders(MaxFolderNo - 1)

        While (Not ioReader.EndOfData)
            Dim arrCurrentRow As String() = ioReader.ReadFields()
            If arrCurrentRow.Length = 12 Then
                Dim FolderIndex As Integer = 0
                For FolderIndex = 0 To MaxFolderNo - 1
                    StrcCurrentRow.Folders(FolderIndex) = arrCurrentRow(FolderIndex)
                Next
                StrcCurrentRow.TagName = arrCurrentRow(FolderIndex)
                StrcCurrentRow.SAPFL = arrCurrentRow(FolderIndex + 1)
                StrcCurrentRow.SAPEqNO = arrCurrentRow(FolderIndex + 2)
                tempList.Add(StrcCurrentRow)
            Else
Error handling
            End If

        End While
        PublicDatabaseList = tempList
        Return Nothing

    End Function
```

Comment: What does the debugger tell you when you step through the code?

Comment: There is no exception from the debugger

Comment: I didn't ask if there was an exception. I asked what the debugger told you about the code execution when you step through the code.

Comment: when updating the array for the next iteration the value of the List.structure.array also changed automatically

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue looks to be the fact that you only ever create one `String` array, thus you just keep overwriting the same elements every time.  Inside the loop, you should be creating a new array and populating it:

```
StrcCurrentRow.Folders = New String(MaxFolderNo - 1) {}

For FolderIndex = 0 To MaxFolderNo - 1
    StrcCurrentRow.Folders(FolderIndex) = arrCurrentRow(FolderIndex)
Next
```

You can get rid of the `ReDim` outside the loop too.

Having said all that, I'd change that type from a structure to class and just have the class create its own array each time or perhaps even use a collection instead.

Comment: I was trying to think how to answer without getting bogged down explaining reference types etc

Comment: @jmcilhinney many thanks that worked for me, but can you explain why that happened ? How definition of variable affect another variable without calling the other

Comment: It's got nothing to do with definition of variables. It has to do with creation of objects. As I have already said, the issue was that you only ever created one array and kept reusing it. Every item in your list was referring to the same array and that array can only contain one set of elements - the last values you assigned to those elements. If you want each item to refer to an array containing the elements it had when you added the item to the list then each item must refer to a different array, which means that you must create a new array for each item, not reuse an existing array.

Answer (score 0):

Move this line:

```
Dim StrcCurrentRow As DataBaseStrc = Nothing
```

Inside the while loop at its start.
You are not setting it each time, thus there is only one object and you keep updating it every loop.

Comment: That's not the issue.  The code's a bit dodgy but the type is a structure so there's no issue with reusing the same one.  The issue is that fact that the same `String` array is being used every time.